# A topological space $X$ which can be $drawn$, whose fundamental group is $S_3$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Does there exist an example of a topological space $X$ which can be *drawn*, whose fundamental group is $S_3$? I know that every group is the fundamental group of a topological space, but I need a concrete example.

Comment: No example exists for any reasonable definition of "drawn". Even in the easier case of $S_2$ you can't actually draw the simplest example, the projective plane.

Comment: This question is a better fit for math.stackexchange.

Comment: @DanPetersen: you can "draw" the projective plane as an identification space. To me, this is a reasonable instance of being "drawn."

Comment: The questioner is not clear as to what 'drawn' is intended to mean. Please spell out more what your motivation is so that answers can be more helpful to you.

Comment: You say you need a concrete example -- but do you really need to *draw* one? :-)

Comment: The space of 3-element subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$ might be what you're looking for. You can draw its points (sort of).